# Truncate once in a year

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table which contains a Date field and it contains values by CURDATE() Is there a way to truncate it once in the beginning of every year only once

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA(
id INT(50) PRIMARY KEY,
modified_on DATE
}

INSERT INTO tableA VALUES(1,CURDATE())
```

How to truncate it at the beginning of every year once once
Something like

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tableA
     CASE WHEN (YEAR(tableA.modified_date) != YEAR(CURDATE()))
```

But it is not working

Comment: Set up a script which truncates the table to run on a schedule. e.g. using crontab in linux. Scheduling is not a job which databases themselves are built for.

Comment: Or use the MySQL event scheduler directly: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-overview.html In any case, your `TRUNCATE` syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

`TRUNCATE` is all or nothing. You can do a `DELETE FROM <table> WHERE <conditions>` but this loses the speed advantages of `TRUNCATE`.

```
Delete from tableA
where (YEAR(tableA.modified_date) != YEAR(CURDATE()))
```

Comment: That really gave a lot of new ideas to implement something in a new way thank you +1 :)